# How do I shuffle a list containing only functions

Tags: python, list, function

I have 44 different ASCII images in print statements saved in functions like cement_mixer() etc, all of which are contained in a list. I need to be able to shuffle this list for the game I am creating to work properly.

I have tried the list.shuffle() and I have tried the code shown below.

```
def scrambled(RandomList):
    dest = RandomList[:]
    random.shuffle(dest)
    return dest
```

Some code  found here which will only output `[none, none, none etc...` when printed in `print(scrambled(list))`.
If anyone can help that would be great as this is for school and I am not incredibly well versed in this yet.

Comment: Shuffling a list works the same no matter what it contains. I don't see how this can return `None, ...` unless `RandomList` already contains that. So the problem is probably with how you're creating the list when calling the function. Please post a [mre].

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle: "To shuffle an immutable sequence and return a new shuffled list, use `sample(x, k=len(x))` instead."